# Changing Master-Detail to Lookup, who becomes Owner?

Tags: lookup, master-detail

When we convert a master-detail relationship to a lookup, who will be the owner of the child records?

Answer (score 6):

The `OwnerId` value from the Master record is used to set the value of the `OwnerId` on the child records when the relationship is changed from Master-Detail to a Lookup.

Additionally, the Org-Wide defaults for the child object are used to set the sharing on the child records. This usually needs to be reviewed after converting the field type to ensure that the appropriate users can see records relevant to them.